# Get exponent of NSDecimalNumber in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, ios

Given an NSDecimalNumber, how can I find the exponent (scale)?

Although it should in principle be possible to do this by first converting to an NSString followed by some ugly string manipulation, I'd rather avoid it.

With a Java BigDecimal, I can call the [scale()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#scale%28%29) method to get the scale.

Does a similarly concise method exist for NSDecimalNumber?

Comment: Could you please tell us why do you need to know the exponent?

Comment: Note that `BigDecimal.scale` is not actually an exponent. For a `BigDecimal`, `2.0` is not equal to `2.00` although they contain the same value. Exponent doesn't really have a mathematical meaning, it has only meaning in a representation of the number.

Answer (score 3):

If you really need the exponent for some reason (other than simply display, which you can configure a number formatter to give you), you can get the primitive double with the `-doubleValue` method and then use `frexp(3)` to get the mantissa and exponent values.

The whole design behind objects for doing and storing floating point math is that you can handle computational and precision errors more effectively, however, the limitation of that design is once you convert from a scalar (such as a `double` or the combination of a mantissa and exponent), you are expected to stay within the object framework and not convert back to a (potentially) less precise format.

I suggest using the `-doubleValue` is the best option, since other answers suggest accessing private structure records which may change, and using these suggests no precision loss, when, in fact, there very well may be (as documented in the header files). When converting to a double, you and those who use/read your code know exactly what precision errors may be possible because the type is very well understood and very well documented.

Finally, if you want to be sure if a conversion is going to cause an error, you can create and use an [NSDecimalNumberHandler](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDecimalNumberHandler_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003645) which will give you information about what kind of rounding/precision errors you can expect when converting to the double scalar type.

I also suggest you add an enhancement request using the apple bug reporter stating that you'd like access to the exponent directly as well as possibly adding a higher precision type, like a `-longDoubleValue` method.

*Edit includes more information*

Comment: Converting a `big decimal` into a `double` will destroy the precision. Wrong solution.

Comment: @Sulthan unfortunately, it's the best that the framework provides for at the moment. Converting to a `NSDecimal` and reading private records (as suggested in other answers) is not only completely wrong, but if you look at comments in the headers, it *specifies* that the conversion will be silently in-exact (so you have the EXACT same issue as converting to a double, but you trick anyone reading your code--and possibly yourself--into thing it's SAFE). At least you *know* what the issues are when converting to a double precision type.

Comment: @JasonCoco Of course, when a `NSDecimalNumber` contains a `float` or a `BOOL`, converting it into a `NSDecimal` won't be exact. BUT the lose of precision will be on a different scale than conversion from a `NSDecimal` to a `double`. It's like trying to convert `double` to a `char`. I don't defend use of private records, but this is not a solution either.

Comment: @Sulthan It's absolutely nothing like converting a double to a char for reasons you're clearly knowledgeable of. You also have no idea what the potential loss of precision will be converting from an `NSDecimalNumber` to an `NSDecimal`. The only safe option that avoids string manipulation is using a double and using the number handler to tell if the number will be representable as a double or not, and if not, what the estimated loss of precision will be. If not further computation is necessary on the number, the loss may be acceptable. That's not your decision, it's the implementer's.

Answer (score 2):

You can access it on `NSDecimal`:

```
int exponent = decimalNumber.decimalValue._exponent;
```

Comment: Except that "The fields of NSDecimal are private." — https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html ; it's private API usage Apple would be extraordinarily unlikely to spot but private API usage all the same.

Comment: (aside: presumably because there are lots of instances where the number won't be in normalised form; e.g. `NSDecimalNumber` may have used `NSDecimalNormalize` at some point and there's no guarantee it will have undone that)

Comment: This is even worse in that not only are you accessing private records which are specifically documented as *do not access*, but the conversion to `NSDecimal` may cause side effects/precision errors which may not be expected, while the conversion to a `double` is known to have specific precision restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't look like [NSDecimalNumber](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDecimalNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html) has an equivalent. I think you may have to write your own.

If you don't mind digging around a bit (and ignoring documentation warnings), however, you might look at the [NSDecimal structure](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000018-BAJEJDDJ) that gets returned from [`-decimalValue`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDecimalNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000179-decimalValue) - it has a number of fields that you could probably get to. Whether this is subjectively better or worse than your NSString manipulations is up to you.

Comment: On second thought, there's a documented and less complicated way to do this in Jason Coco's answer above. Leaving this here for completeness, though it's probably not the best choice :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the expression to be on base-10 form (frexp(3) seems to only do base-2), you could try this:

```
double mantissa = [someDecimalNumber doubleValue];
int exp = 0;

if (mantissa >= 1.0f) {
    while (mantissa >= 1.0f) {
        mantissa = mantissa / 10.0f;
        exp++;
    }
} else {
    while (mantissa*10.0f < 1.0f) {
        mantissa = mantissa * 10.0f;
        exp--;
    }
}

NSLog(@"%f = %f x 10^%d", [someDecimalNumber doubleValue], mantissa, exp);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can compare the number with `NSDecimalNumber` instances created with mantissa equal to 1, changing the exponent. It can work like a binary search.